# Detect closed socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I'm writing a multithreaded server which at the moment just receives a string and send it back capitalized.

My problem is that the server doesn't detect when the connection to the client is lost and the client Handler thread is therefore kept running.

I have a while loop which handles the client requests and I'd like to break out of this loop if the connection is closed/lost.

This is the code of the ClientHandler

```
try {
            inFromServer = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

            OutputStream outToServer = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            while(!clientSocket.isClosed()){
                if(in.available() > 0) {
                    String str = in.readUTF(); //Should catch EOF
                    System.out.println("[+] From " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + " received: " + str);
                    String response = str.toUpperCase();

                    out.writeUTF(response);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("[+] Closing client");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have tried to make the while loop like this:

```
while(!clientSocket.isClosed() && inFromServer.read() != -1)
```

But this isn't working...

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can, this is why some protocols (like IRC) ping regularly their clients and wait for an answer with a time-out.

Comment: `Socket.isClosed()` detects a closed *socket* all right, but what you're really asking about is a closed *connection*, closed by the peer. @jtahlborn's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Socket.isClosed()` will only return true if *you* have closed the *socket.* The way you detect that a *connection* has been closed by the peer is by reading from it. You should not be using `in.available()`.  instead, just read from the socket and you will get an exception when the socket is closed.

Comment: Thanks. I know that isClosed is kept True even though the connection is lost. My plan was to have the check from inside the loop make a clientSocket.close() call if it finds out that the connection is lost.